# Is there a way to measure the structural strength of a connection?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I'm designing a very large spacecraft, and I'd like to attach an arm to the spacecraft.

**Is there a way to measure just how strong the attachment is?**

In engineering terms, this arm is a cantilever beam, and I'd like to know how much load it can take on the end before it breaks off.

[image: end-loaded cantilever beam]

To attach this arm to the spacecraft:

- only stock parts may be used (no mods), and
- the arm can be added to the spacecraft in the assembly building.

Comment: Without launching the craft and just trying it out? Without mods which provide more information? I don't think so.

Comment: do it the real kerbal way, see how many separatrons you can bolt on and fire off before it has an unclean seperation

Comment: @IG_42, that's basically what I ended up doing.  I'll post an answer with my results in case it helps anyone else.

Comment: So, have you tried it yet?

Comment: I would like to know as well.  Have you tried this out yet?  Results?